# How to make eclipse to show error line?

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm using eclipse indigo

my eclipse shows that there is some error but it doesn't show the red line and also doesn't show what the error is , it just shows that red cross icon

my eclipse screen shot :
[image: eclipse screen shot]

Comment: Are there any messages in the `Problems` view.

Comment: no it doesn't show either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show error line go to `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors` and check `Text as` to `Native Problem Underline`

Answer (score 0):

if you mouse over the little x's it should tell you the problem, the first error is that you need to add a cast to the find view by id so

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`

and I'm not 100% sure on the second one but it think it should be this, or something similar.

`imageView.setImageURI(URI.parse(getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)));`

Alternatively it might be because the setting of the image view was wrong.

Comment: i know that what the problem is but the problem is that it doesn't show the error line